# xbindkeys press middle mouse button

Tags: mouse, hardware

I've an MX Revolution mouse and I've mapped the search key as the button 2 so that I can perform middle click. The desired function that I'm looking for is to be able to use the button to press and hold so I can pan around a 3d model in blender. Instead, I am getting a fast alternation of button press and button release which has a slight delay that is causing the panning to be jerky. The line that I use in `.xbindkeysrc` looks like this:

```
"echo 'buttonpress 2 buttonrelease 2' | xmacroplay :0"
    m:0x0 + c:225
    XF86Search
```

I suspect the problem is the buttonrelease 2 command. but I'm not sure. Is there anyway I can make the button press and hold command until I release the button on the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found the answer. I used `xdotool` instead of `xmacroplay` and used the following code:

```
"echo 'mousedown 2' | xdotool - :0"
    m:0x0 + c:225
"echo 'mouseup 2' | xdotool - :0"
  release + m:0x0 + c:225
    XF86Search
```

The key is the "`release +`" feature. without it, the `mousedown 2` will force a constant click on middle mouse button. A new code `mouseup 2` that is set to activate on release is how to fix it.